# In PowerShell how do I load multiple values into a variable?

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I have a requirement at work to check several registry key values and I want to automate this process using PowerShell. One of the registry keys that I check has 3 values and I am not able to successfully check it using my PowerShell script.

I do not believe I am correctly loading the `$value` variable so that it can be compared to the value of `$path`.

```
$path = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer).NullSessionPipe

$value = “netlogon samr lsarpc”

if ($path -ne $value) {
    Write-Host “Value is incorrect or missing.”
} else {
    Write–Host “Config is correct.”
}
```

I expect the output to be

> Config is correct.

Instead I get

> Value is incorrect or missing.

Using Regedit I can see that the key has the correct values.

Comment: What is $path?.

Comment: the `-match` operator uses regex, so you can do something like `$Thing -match 'ValOne|ValTwo|ValThree'` to get a match on any one of the values. the pipe is the way regex does `or` ... [*grin*]

Comment: PLEASE do not use curly 'smart-quotes' in code. Replace them with straight ones

Answer (score 0):

`NullSessionPipe` apparently is a REG_MULTI_SZ, meaning that the data is returned as an array of strings. You could do `"$path" -ne $value` to mangle the array into a flat string, but that would imply that the order of the substrings is identical in both strings. A better approach is to compare arrays via `Compare-Object`.

```
$path  = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\...).NullSessionPipe
$value = 'netlogon', 'samr', 'lsarpc'

if (Compare-Object $path $value) {
    'arrays differ'
} else {
    'arrays are equal'
}
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for your response.  When I tried your code I got the same result of "Value is incorrect or missing."  Decided to check the value of the variables and this is what I found.

PS C:\> $path
netlogon
 samr
 lsarpc

PS C:\> $value
netlogon
samr
lsarpc

As you can see $path prints out is a space before samr and lsarpc.  Could the spaces be throwing the comparison off?  If so how do I insert the same spaces in $value?

Comment: @Steve Actually, no, I can't see that from your comment. Please edit your question if you need to provide additional information. But yes, if there are additional spaces that would mean the strings are different.

Comment: @Steve If spaces around the items are the cause of not comparing correctly, simply remove them with `$path  = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\...).NullSessionPipe | ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()}`

Answer (score 0):

@Ansgar, After some experimenting I was able to get the script to work.  I deleted the blank spaces and added a carriage return after netlogon and samr.  It works perfectly!!!

$path = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer).NullSessionPipe

$value = 'netlogon',
' samr',
' lsarpc'

if (Compare-Object $path $value) {
    'arrays differ'
} else {
    'arrays are equal'
}